# HQL 'With statement' cause an additional join

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

The HQL With statement produce strange behavior. I expect the following query:

```
select
    s.id, s.nom,s.dateDebutPublication,s.dateFinPublication,r.codeUtilisateur
from
    Sondage s left outer join
    s.repondant r with r.codeUtilisateur=:utilisateur
```

to produce this sql request:

```
select ...
from
    SON_SONDG sondage0_ 
left outer join
    SON_REPND repondant1_ 
        on sondage0_.SEQ_SONDG=repondant1_.SEQ_SONDG 
        and (
            repondant1_.CODE_UTILS=?
        )
```

instead, it create an extra join, which return way more lines

```
left outer join
    SON_REPND repondant1_ 
        on sondage0_.SEQ_SONDG=repondant1_.SEQ_SONDG 
left outer join
    SON_REPND repondant2_ 
        on repondant1_.SEQ_REPND=repondant2_.SEQ_REPND 
        and (
            repondant2_.CODE_UTILS=?
        )
```

what would be the correct way to write de HQL query so it return my expected sql query?

Comment: could you provide your hql query please?

Comment: The hql querry is the first code block, What is missing from it?

Comment: Why do you use with instead of on??

Comment: because HQL do not recognize the on keyword

Comment: What hibernate version do you use? Have you tried `with r.codeUtilisateur.id = :utilisateurId` yet?

Comment: hibernate 4.2.0 for JPA 2.0, it is a 3 or 4 year old project. codeUtilisateur (userCode) is  a string value, not an entity.